# 404 Not Found for static files in the public directory with Express.js on Vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vercel, static-files

I have an Express.js application deployed on Vercel that serves static files from a public directory.

Despite the `admin.html` file being present in the directory, trying to access it via my vercel app results in a 404 Not Found error. (Just showing `Cannot GET /index.html`)

The application works as expected locally, but when deployed to Vercel, static files are not served correctly.

This is my data structure - it should be set up properly:

```
/
|-- server.js
|-- public/
    |-- admin.html
    |-- index.html
    |-- //other relevant html]
```

How i'm setting up my file serving:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

// ...

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

My vercel.json config file:

```
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "server.js",
      "use": "@vercel/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/server.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

My vercel logs aren't any help, just `404 - GET /`

How can I make these files serve correctly?

Comment: if possible could you share the github repo link ?

Comment: @ullaskunder [here!](https://github.com/TheMiningD/QAHSToast)

Comment: check PR in github